# how to create a new dataframe which contains summ of certain columns of a few other dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a few dataframes: df1, df2, df3, with same header: parameter1, parameter2, ..paramer5

How to create a new dataframe which will summ (or will do other math operations which i choose)?
I did:

1. created a new dataframe with one column date
2. added second column 'parameter2' of this new dataframe as summ of 'parameter2' from df1, df2, df3

```
resultingdataframe=df1['parameter1'] 
resultingdataframe['parameter2']=df1['parameter2']+df2['parameter2']+df3['parameter2']
```

Got error, and resulting column is zero, but it should not be a zero.

Comment: Your issue is most likely related to something you did **before** the code that you showed here. `df1 = df1.copy() ; df2 = df2.copy() ; df3 = df3.copy()` should solve your issue.

Comment: @mozway thank you! Could you please explain more

Comment: Please read the duplicate first.

Comment: @mozway thank you. I got the issue. By writing resultingdataframe=df1['parameter1'] , I created not a dataframe but pandas.core.series.Series.  I had to create a new dataframe from df1, and then replace required columns as I want.